# MySQL Join with looped reference query

Tags: mysql

I have a slightly complex table structure that I'm trying to query for a search function, but my queries keep timing out.  Basically, it's a book search, and I'm focusing on the subject portion of that search.

The subjects table is simple (id and title), but there's a link table that refers it back to itself called subjects_subjects, which complicates things.

```
**subjects_subjects**
id (key)
subject_id (reference to subjects table)
see_subject_id (another reference to subjects table)
```

The reason for the looping reference is to catch subjects that don't contain any books, but point to subjects that do.  For example, there's no books under the 'Travel' subject, so that subject has a link to 'Explorers' and 'Voyages' that do contain books. The point is to make searching easier.

So what I'm trying to do is allow the user to search for 'Travel', but return results from 'Explorers' and 'Voyages'.  Here's my query that times out:

```
SELECT
    BK.id,
    BK.title

FROM
    books BK

            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        books_subjects BS
              ON BS.book_id = BK.id

WHERE 
    BS.subject_id IN (1639,3173)
    OR BS.subject_id IN 
    (
        SELECT
            SS.see_subject_id

        FROM
            subjects_subjects SS

        WHERE
            SS.subject_id IN (1639,3173)

    )

GROUP BY 
    BK.books_id
```

Extra info: There are 17000 books and over 3000 subjects in the database, with roughly 84000 book/subject references.

Can anyone help me figure out where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two things that MySQL optimizes poorly:

1. `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.
2. `IN (SELECT ...)`

Instead of `OR`, use two queries that you combine with `OR`. And instead of `IN (SELECT ...)` use a `JOIN`.

Also, you shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN` if you don't need to return rows from the first table with no matches in the second table, use `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT b.id, b.title
FROM books AS b
JOIN books_subjects AS bs ON bs.book_id = b.id
WHERE bs.subject_id IN (1639, 3173)
UNION
SELECT books AS b
JOIN books_subjects AS bs ON bs.book_id = b.id
JOIN subjects_subjects AS ss ON bs.subject_id = ss.see_subject_id
WHERE ss.subject_id IN (1639, 3173)
```